# Reading a CSV file using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, iis, internet-explorer-8

I'm using IE8 with jQuery 1.9.1. I want the user to select a csv file. The contents of the file should be displayed in the alert. So far, I have been able to do this:

```
function getCsv(filepath) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: filepath,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("Status: " + xhr.status + "     Error: " + thrownError);
        }
    });
};

$("#upload").click(function() {
    var fname = $("#filename").val();
    fname = fname.replace(/\\/g, "/");
    fname = "file:///" + fname;
    getCsv(fname);
});
```

This works great when I open the html file directly(by double clicking the file). But when I deploy this on a server(IIS Server) it gives the error alert.

Also i have used `jQuery.support.cors = true` to avoid problems with CORS.

Comment: Use the error handler to output the reason of why does the request fail.

Comment: You can't use AJAX to get a local `file:///`

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12289296/901048

Comment: @OfirBaruch: It says "No Transport"

Comment: Consider what @Blazemonger mentioned.

Comment: @Blazemonger: jQuery-CSV uses the content of the csv file. But I'm not able to get the content itself. My actual requirement is to display the content of the csv file in a [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/). currently i'm copy-pasting the content of csv file in a text area and then using it. That works fine though.

Comment: @OfirBaruch can you suggest any other method to do this?

Comment: Where is the file you're trying to display? On the client computer, on the server, or on a third system somewhere? AJAX is only suitable for getting it from a different URL. You need [HTML file upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery) to get it from the client computer.

Answer (score 1):

See either:

- [Receive .csv file as data in ajax success function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250065/receive-csv-file-as-data-in-ajax-success-function) using an external service to convert the csv to jsonp, or
- https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv for a jquery library to convert csv within the client (but then need the csv has to come from the same origin)