# Ajax call fails in Chrome, but works in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

Any idea why the following Ajax call fails in Chrome, but not Firefox?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "text/csv; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "text",
    cache: false,                    
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/param1/param2?param3=csv&otherParams=type1,type2,type3"
 })
    .done(function(data) {
        console.debug("Data received from ajax call: " + data);
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         console.error("Data request failed (" + textStatus + "): " + errorThrown);
         console.debug(jqXHR.responseText);
    });
```

The URL that I am calling should return the data in csv format. I'm using jQuery 1.8.2. This works in Firefox, but not Chrome for some reason. The error message that I print out is:

```
Data request failed (text/csv): text/csv
```

Interestingly, in Chrome I can see the data returned in the `jqXHR.responseText`, so I can't figure out why it's throwing an error. I assume it has something to do with my not specifying the csv format properly, but I thought setting the `dataType` or `contentType` would fix that. What am I missing?

I realize this is a common problem, but in spite of my Googling and searching around Stack Overflow, I have been unable to find a solution that fixes this problem for me. All the suggestions I've found have said to set the `contentType`, the `dataType`, or the `cache` to false. As you can see, none of these solutions has worked for me. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: try **dataType: "text"** in your scenario

Comment: Isn't that what I have?

Comment: same origin? is your JS and your CSV on the same domain? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250065/receive-csv-file-as-data-in-ajax-success-function

Comment: Yes, they're on the same domain. There shouldn't be any same origin issues.